# Insert shortcode in post editor from javascript (Visual / HTML)

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor

I want to insert a shortcode in the Wordpress Post Editor from javascript (not a tinymce plugin). I currently use:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "[SHORTCODE]test[/SHORTCODE] ");
```

but this only seems to work when the editor is in "Visual" mode (and sometimes activeEditor == null). How do I accomplish this regardless of the state of the editor? (I'd think this is a fairly common scenario)

Answer (score 2):

I was pulling my hair out on this one, but I might have figured it out.

Try this (with jQuery):

```
if( ! tinyMCE.activeEditor || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden()) {
  jQuery('textarea#content').val("[SHORTCODE]test[/SHORTCODE] ");
} else {
  tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertRawHTML', false, "[SHORTCODE]test[/SHORTCODE] ");
}
```

Basically, you need to set the value of the textarea directly if the editor is hidden.